# Страница удаления

Tags: php, mysql

Есть простой скрипт. Там через GET параметр передается id записи и название таблицы и происходит удаление этой записи, и потом через Header отправляется назад. Возникла необходимость добавить подтверждение удаления. Что-то не могу сообразить как. Получается, нужно сохранить входящие гет... показать страницу с формой подтверждения и потом при сабмите удалить запись и вернутся назад.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А нужна именно страница подтверждения на удаление? Просто вопрос сойдет через js? :)
Ну тогда вот вариант:
по Вашему описанию, есть ссылка, кликнув на которую происходит удаление записи в таблице, а затем возврат на страницу с ссылкой, например, `<a href="/admin/action.php?act=del&amp;id=5&amp;backurl=/admin/index.php">удалить запись</a>`.
Теперь попробуем удалить запись с подтверждением.
Создадим js файлик, в который поместим следующий код

```
function confirmdel(id, backurl) {

    var answer = confirm("Вы действительно хотите удалить запись № "+id+"?");

    if (answer){
        window.location = "/admin/action.php?act=del&amp;id="+id+"&amp;backurl="+backurl;
    }
}
```

а ссылку, которая была в примере, заменяем на

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirmdel('5','/admin/index.php')">удалить запись</a>
```

Теперь, когда Вы будете кликать по ссылке, то сначала Вас спросят **Вы действительно хотите удалить запись № 5?** И в зависимости от Вашего решения будет совершено или удаление записи или ничего не будет.

Answer (score 1):

В первоначальной форме добавляем хидден поле с именем delete и значением confirm

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['delete'])){
  if($_GET['delete']=='confirm'){
    //Выводим форму подтверждения, передающую параметр delete со значением 'ok'   
  }elseif($_GET['delete']=='confirm'){
    //Удаляем все, что требуется
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($_GET['delete'])){
    // форма удаления с action = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&delete'
}
else{
    //удаление, перенаправление
}
```

А js'у я не доверяю - он может не подгрузиться, глюкнуть или вообще быть отключенным.

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, именно так, либо при клике через JS вызывать модальное окно подтверждения.

Comment: через JS уже не получится, ссылок сильно много. и их менять не хотелось.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше с помощью Javascript перед самой отправкой запроса на удаление используйте глобальный метод confirm - http://javascript.ru/confirm